# SSRS Pre Loading Dropdownlist from Web Service Not Working

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a Report that needs to populate a list of customers before the user has the option to view the report. I have 2 datasets 1 is for the customer list and the other is for the main view. When i run the report if i specify a default value for the parameter for the dataset that gets customers it works fine but if i do not specify a default value and use the parameter that is passed from the calling application i get the following error:
The report parameter 'Customer' has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter "userId", Forward dependencies are not valid

Where i am the most confused is that if i pass the value via the calling app why does it act like it does not have it yet?

Comment: Are you trying to pass in the value of 'Customer' or the value of 'userId'?

Comment: i am trying to pass the value of userid

Answer (score 0):

The userId parameter is lower on your list of parameters.  Reporting Services is trying to resolve the parameters in the order in which they are listed in BIDS and the ReportViewer control.  Based on your error, the Customer parameter has a dependency on the userId parameter and you can't resolve the Customer parameter until the userId parameter is resolved.  To do this, you must move Customer parameter to a lower position on the list or move the userId to a higher position on the list.

Comment: I moved Customer to the bottom of the Main Data dataset parameter and UserID is the only one in the DropDownList DataSet Parameters and i still get the exact same error. through research i have seen where many ppl have the same issue and it looks like it could just be the version of ssrs i am using, unfortunately its the version i have to use for this project. I assume that if the UserId is the top parameter on both data sets it would go in that order but it still errors.